# kubernetes: error: Unexpected args: [create]

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Follow guide at https://operatorhub.io/operator/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com (press button Install), on Windows 10 pro x64 . Error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>curl -sL https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/releases/download/v0.21.2/install.sh | bash -s v0.21.2
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/catalogsources.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterserviceversions.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/installplans.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/olmconfigs.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/operatorconditions.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/operatorgroups.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/operators.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/subscriptions.operators.coreos.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/catalogsources.operators.coreos.com condition met
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterserviceversions.operators.coreos.com condition met
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/installplans.operators.coreos.com condition met
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/olmconfigs.operators.coreos.com condition met
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/operatorconditions.operators.coreos.com condition met
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/operatorgroups.operators.coreos.com condition met
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/operators.operators.coreos.com condition met
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/subscriptions.operators.coreos.com condition met
namespace/olm created
namespace/operators created
serviceaccount/olm-operator-serviceaccount created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:operator-lifecycle-manager created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/olm-operator-binding-olm created
olmconfig.operators.coreos.com/cluster created
deployment.apps/olm-operator created
deployment.apps/catalog-operator created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-olm-edit created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-olm-view created
operatorgroup.operators.coreos.com/global-operators created
operatorgroup.operators.coreos.com/olm-operators created
clusterserviceversion.operators.coreos.com/packageserver created
catalogsource.operators.coreos.com/operatorhubio-catalog created
Waiting for deployment "olm-operator" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
deployment "olm-operator" successfully rolled out
Waiting for deployment "catalog-operator" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
deployment "catalog-operator" successfully rolled out
Package server phase: Installing
Package server phase: Succeeded
deployment "packageserver" successfully rolled out

C:\Users\Administrator>kubectl create -f https://operatorhub.io/install/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com.yamlkubectl create -f https://operatorhub.io/install/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com.yaml
error: Unexpected args: [create]
See 'kubectl create -h' for help and examples

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

```
error: Unexpected args: [create]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl create -f 
https://operatorhub.io/install/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com.yamlkubectl 
create -f 
https://operatorhub.io/install/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com.yaml
```

duplicate create -f,
so you need use only `create -f` as:

```
kubectl create -f 
https://operatorhub.io/install/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com.yaml 
https://operatorhub.io/install/postgresql-operator-dev4devs-com.yaml
```